# How to sort javascript set array when we getting diffrent type of array everytime

Tags: javascript, sorting

```
var array = [355, 1, 488, 6, 4, 78, 63, 4, 3, 1];
 //      array = [9, 2, 5, 4, 6],
   //    array = ["1001", "25", "36", "25"],
     // array = ["c1-ca-10-1a-11-f4","c1-ca-10-1a-11-f5","c1-ca-10-1a-11-f1" //];
      assetData = new Set(); 

      array.forEach(function(data) {
      assetData.add(data);
      });

     assetData = Array.from(assetData)


        assetData.sort(function() {
        return 0.5 - Math.random();
       });
       console.log(assetData); 
        var newArray = [];
        Array.prototype.push.apply(newArray, assetData

);
```

In above code i want to sort all arrays.i have 4 type of array i need to sort all of them.

Comment: that's a great ambition

Comment: In the above code, you throw the first three arrays away immediately, because you are setting the same `array` variable each time. The only `.sort()` function shown does a random sort, so the data type of the array elements is irrelevant. It's really not clear what you're trying to do here. Please update the question to make it clear what the expected output is for your example input(s).

Comment: `var array = [355, 1, 488, 6, 4, 78, 63, 4, 3, 1];
       array = [9, 2, 5, 4, 6],
       array = ["1001", "25", "36", "25"],
      array = ["c1-ca-10-1a-11-f4","c1-ca-10-1a-11-f5","c1-ca-10-1a-11-f1" ];` ===> `var       array = ["c1-ca-10-1a-11-f4","c1-ca-10-1a-11-f5","c1-ca-10-1a-11-f1" ];`

Answer (score 0):

Below is the best way to handle all kind of array element sorting.

```
var //array = [355, 1, 488, 6, 4, 78, 63, 4, 3, 1];
     // array = [9, 2, 5, 4, 6],
     //array = ["1001", "25", "36", "25"],
      array = ["c1-ca-10-1a-11-f4","c1-ca-10-1a-11-f5","c1-ca-10-1a-11-f1"];
      assetData = new Set(); 

      array.forEach(function(data) {
      assetData.add(data);
      });

     assetData = Array.from(assetData)

assetData.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
       console.log(assetData); 
        var newArray = [];
        Array.prototype.push.apply(newArray, assetData

);
```